# How to pass default parameters to laravel controller in a get route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a route like that:

```
Route::get('category/{id}/{date?}', array('as' => 'category/date', 'uses' => 'Controller@getCategory'));
```

I want to run @getCategory with default parameters when called '/' root route. So if '/' route called, getCategory function should run with id=1 and date=2015-12-18.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Register it as a separate route:

```php
Route::get('/', 'Controller@getCategory')->named('home');
Route::get('category/{id}/{date?}', 'Controller@getCategory')->named('category/date');
```

Then in your controller, set default values for those arguments:

```php
public function getCategory($id = 1, $date = '2015-12-18')
{
    // do your magic...
}
```

Comment: Of course it is one way to do this. But is there any way to do this in one route and not in controller?

Comment: Id also like to know how to pass static parameter in route. Can't find answer anywhere. :(

Comment: What is the solution if you want to use different default values according to the route pattern?

Comment: how do i access the endpoint without id

Answer (score 6):

Set a default value for the route with Laravel 9.x

```php
Route::get('categories/{id}/{date?}', 'CategoryController@getCategory')
     ->name('category-date')
     ->defaults('date', '2023-02-13');
```

Comment: you can add another `->defaults($key, $value)` for each parameter that needs one

Answer (score 2):

first, please excuse me for my bad English writing.
to answer the question of ***emotality*** and ***Robert*** :
we can use a class in routes/web.php
and then in controller use it, for example :

***Routes/web.php***

```
class SomeVars {
    public $var1 = 'en';
    public $var2 = 'fr';
}   
Route::get('/localization/{vars}','LocalizationController@index');
```

***LocalizationController.php***

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use SomeVars;
class LocalizationController extends Controller {
    public function index(Request $request, SomeVars $vars) {
        echo $vars->var1;
        echo $vars->var2;
    }
}
```

Now if you browse : someSite/localization/anything
see this result :

en
fr

---

and if you need this class in the all method of your controller , you can use this way :

***Routes/web.php***

```
class SomeVars {
    public $var1 = 'en';
    public $var2 = 'fr';
}   
Route::get('/localization','LocalizationController@index');
```

***LocalizationController.php***

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use SomeVars;
class LocalizationController extends Controller {
    public $vars;
    public function __construct(SomeVars $vars){
        $this->vars = $vars;
        
    }
    public function index(Request $request) {
        echo $this->vars->var1;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $this->vars->var2;
    }
}
```

Now, if you can this address in your browser : someSite/localization
can see this result again :

en
fr

i hope this help, thanks, hope to God

Answer (score 0):

The **routes**, For example in My case I had polymorphic relationship for comments

```
 Route::get('posts-comments/{commentable_id}', ['uses' => 'CommentController@fetchComments', 'commentable' => 'posts']);

 Route::get('video-comments/{commentable_id}', ['uses' => 'CommentController@fetchComments', 'commentable' => 'videos']);
```

Then In the **controller**:

```
 public function fetchComments(Request $request, commentable_id)
  {
    $commentable = $request->route()->getAction()['commentable'];
  }
```

I hope this answers your question

Answer (score -1):

It works for me with a `"?" {date?}`  in the **route**, and putting a default value in the **anonimus function**.`$date = null`

**Route**

```
Route::get('category/{id}/{date?}', function($date = null) {
   if ($date === null)
      //Option 1
   else
      //Option 2    
});
```